# Remove comma from last result in nested forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects, nested-loops

I'm trying to return the following values to insert in a SQL statement:

```
('apple', 'fruit', 'john@gmail.com'), ('carrot', 'vegetables', 'john@gmail.com'), ('beans', 'vegetables', 'john@gmail.com'), ('milk', 'dairy', 'john@gmail.com'), ('cheese', 'dairy', 'john@gmail.com')
```

Here's the data I have to work with:

```
const email = "john@gmail.com";
const body = {
        "fruit": ["apple"],
        "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"],
        "dairy": ["milk", "cheese"]
};
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
let values = '';

Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
  Object.keys(body[key]).forEach(item => {
    values += `('${body[key][item]}', '${key}', '${email}'),`;
  });
});
```

This returns the correct values, but the last result has a comma on the end which causes the an error when inserted into the SQL.

Any ideas how to rewrite this function to trim the comma from the last iteration? Maybe I should try a different loop, like for(), instead of forEach?

Thanks :)

Comment: Append strings to an array of strings and then use `array.join(',')` to avoid having to write the if statement to detect if the comma should be inserted.

Comment: @JasonAller Yeah, that's probably the cleanest way here

Comment: The second `Object.keys` is not needed since you can just use `item` directly (as shown in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use map/join:

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com";
const body = {
  "fruit": ["apple"],
  "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"],
  "dairy": ["milk", "cheese"]
}; 

const values = Object.keys(body)
 .map(key => 
  body[key]
  .map(item => `('${item}', '${key}', '${email}')`)
  .join(', ')
 )
 .join(', ');

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `slice()` function to remove the last character of string.

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com";
const body = {
        "fruit": ["apple"],
        "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"],
        "dairy": ["milk", "cheese"]
}; 
let values = '';
Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
  Object.keys(body[key]).forEach(item => {
    values += `('${body[key][item]}', '${key}', '${email}'),`;
  });
});
values = values.slice(0,-1)

console.log(values)
```

The better way to that is first `flatMap()` to get a flat array of strings and then use `join()`

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com";
const body = {
        "fruit": ["apple"],
        "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"],
        "dairy": ["milk", "cheese"]
}; 
let values = Object.entries(body)
                      .flatMap(([k,v]) => v.map(a => `('${v}', '${k}', '${email}')`))
                      .join(',')
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the `body` object:

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com";
const body = {
  "fruit": ["apple"],
  "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"],
  "dairy": ["milk", "cheese"]
};

let res = Object.entries(body).reduce((acc, [k, v], i, arr1) =>
{
    v.forEach((e, j, arr2) =>
    {
        acc += `('${e}', '${k}', '${email}')`;
        acc += (i === arr1.length - 1 && j === arr2.length - 1) ? "" : ", ";
    });

    return acc;
}, "");

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code so it only adds the comma when it's required
    let values = '';

```
let separator = '';
Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
  Object.keys(body[key]).forEach(item => {
    values += `('${body[key][item]}', '${key}', '${email}')` + separator;
    separator = ',';
  });
});
```